# How to make FZF BTags command separate public from private methods

Tags: ctags, plugin-fzf, fzf

I spend most of my time doing peer reviews and working on higher level architecture decisions when it comes to the code of my team. So I find the tools that visualizes the code at a higher level to be incredibly useful.

One of my favorites is the `:BTags` command from [fzf](https://github.com/junegunn/fzf) which loads all the methods in the current buffer:

[image]

However I would like this visualizer to annotate the methods as private or public, since as a code reviewer I need to scrutinize the public methods more so than the private methods.

Ideas?